MQTTClient throws error when trying to connect
I'm devopling an application on a PicoW using Visual Studio (Thonny gives the same results).
It uses umqtt.simple:
from machine import Pin, I2C
from time import sleep
import network
from umqtt.simple import MQTTClient
import config

# MQTT Parameters
MQTT_SERVER = config.mqtt_server
MQTT_PORT = 0
MQTT_USER = config.mqtt_username
MQTT_PASSWORD = config.mqtt_password
MQTT_CLIENT_ID = b"rPi_pico_train_1"
MQTT_KEEPALIVE = 7200
MQTT_SSL = True

led = Pin("LED", Pin.OUT)

def flash_led(count):
    _count = count
    while _count > 0:
        led.value(True)
        sleep(0.25)
        led.value(False)
        sleep(0.05)
        _count -= 1

def init_wifi(ssid, password):
    led.value(0)
    wlan = network.WLAN(network.STA_IF)
    wlan.active(True)
    wlan.connect(ssid, password)
    
    connection_timeout = 20
    print("Waiting for WIFI Connection...")
    while connection_timeout > 0:
        if wlan.status() >= 3:
            break
        connection_timeout -= 1
        print(f"Timeout in: {connection_timeout}")
        sleep(1)
    if wlan.status() != 3:
        return False
    else:
        print("Connected!")
        network_info = wlan.ifconfig()
        print(f"IP: {network_info[0]}")
        led.value(1)
    return True

def sub_cb(topic, msg):
    print("New message on topic {}".format(topic.decode('utf-8')))
    msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
    print(msg)

if init_wifi(config.wifi_ssid, config.wifi_password):
    flash_led(2)
else:
    print("NOT CONNECTED TO WIFI")

client = MQTTClient(MQTT_CLIENT_ID, MQTT_SERVER,0, MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD, 3600,{'server_hostname' : MQTT_SERVER})
client.connect()
client.set_callback(sub_cb)
print('Connected to %s MQTT Broker'%(client))
print("Connecting to client")
flash_led(5)
print("Client listening")
while True:
    client.subscribe('trains')
    sleep(1)

Here's my server details:

Presumbly, my client iVar isn't init'd correcly, but having looked at Hive and Tom's Hardware, I've run to a stop.
EDIT
Thanks for @Brits comment about not inclusing client.connect(). I've re-written and started afresh a couple of times and must have missed that!
Unfortunately I still can't connect. The error is now:
Waiting for WIFI Connection...
Connected!
IP: 192.168.1.183
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 69, in <module>
  File "/lib/umqtt/simple.py", line 68, in connect
AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'

The line quoted in the module - line 69 - is the line of my code that contains: client.connect().
How is my code not connecting properly to Hive?

client = MQTTClient(MQTT_CLIENT_ID, MQTT_SERVER,0, MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD, 3600,{'server_hostname' : MQTT_SERVER})
client.set_callback(sub_cb)
print('Connected to %s MQTT Broker'%(client))

You are not calling client.connect i.e.
client = MQTTClient(MQTT_CLIENT_ID, MQTT_SERVER,0, MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD, 3600,{'server_hostname' : MQTT_SERVER})
client.set_callback(sub_cb)
client.connect()
print('Connected to %s MQTT Broker'%(client))

client.connect sets self.sock which subscribe uses (self.sock.write(pkt) - line 157 in simple.py); hence the error.
Update
Ref your subsequent error File "/lib/umqtt/simple.py", line 68, in connect, that line (and the line before) is:
if self.ssl:
            self.sock = self.ssl.wrap_socket(self.sock, server_hostname=self.server)

So self.ssl is set. This will be because you call
client = MQTTClient(MQTT_CLIENT_ID, MQTT_SERVER,0, MQTT_USER, MQTT_PASSWORD, 3600,{'server_hostname' : MQTT_SERVER})

where:
def __init__(
        self,
        client_id,
        server,
        port=0,
        user=None,
        password=None,
        keepalive=0,
        ssl=None,
    ):

so you are setting ssl to {'server_hostname' : MQTT_SERVER}. Unfortunately, based on this discussion and the source, it looks like this parameter changed in version 1.4 and you need something like the following (copied from the discussion):
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLS_CLIENT)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_NONE
client = MQTTClient(client_id=b"kudzai_raspberrypi_picow", server=b"8fbadaf843514ef286a2ae29e80b15a0.s1.eu.hivemq.cloud", port=0, user=b"mydemoclient", password=b"passowrd", keepalive=7200, ssl=context )

Note: Sorry I don't actually use this currently, so cannot provide a fully working example I can just tyy to point out where you probably need to look (and looking at the library source is a good starting point with issues like this, unfortunately to keep the size down and performance up the library does not validate parameters).

That's embaressing, thanks for the spot! I've tried your code above and am now getting a different error: 'dict' object has no attribute 'wrap_socket'.

I’ve marked you as having answered it since in order to continue I should really ask another question. You’re absolutely right but there is clearly something else going on and editing the answer seems unfair to you and the time you’ve spent.

No worries, have tried to address the additional question (sorry - I don't currently have an environment setup that I can use to run this, so can't provide a full working example).
